# How I can catch 3 True in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of true and false I wanna count whenever I have 3 repetitive True.

```
my_list=[True, True, True, True,False, True, True,False]
```

output:
Since the first 3 elements are true and second to forth is also True the output is 2.

```
count=2
```

I did the following but I am looking a better way to change 3 by any number if I want.

```
count=0
for j in my_list:
    if my_list[j]==True and my_list[j+1]==True and my_list[j+2]==True:

count=count+1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @sabik I tried two for loop but I am looking for something better that I can change 3 by any number

Comment: @user15649753 Why can't you change your loop to use a variable?

Comment: @user how? what do u mean?

Comment: It would help to see your code to point out how to change it.

Comment: @user15649753 Please provide your attempt so that we can see what you're aiming for. Like for example, do you want to identify matches based on `bool(x)`, `x == True`, or `x is True`.

Comment: Your example doesn't work... I think you meant to do `for j in range(len(my_list)-2)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use list slicing in conjunction with `all`.

```
consec = 3
count = 0
my_list = [True, True, True, True,False, True, True,False]
for i in range(len(my_list) - consec + 1):
    if all(my_list[i:i+consec]):
        count += 1
print(count)
```

This can also be written in one line using `sum` (as [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987) notes).

```
count = sum(all(my_list[i:i+consec]) for i in range(len(my_list) - consec + 1))
```

Comment: You can turn that into a one-liner: `count = sum(all(my_list[i:i+consec+1]) for i in range(len(my_list) - consec + 1)`.  This takes advantage of `False==0` and `True==1`.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one for loop from index 0 to len(my_list)-2, and then for each iteration, find the sum of 3 consecutive elements starting from the current index (as True=1 and False=0 in python).

```
In [1]: my_list=[True, True, True, True,False, True, True,False]

In [2]: count = sum(1 for i in range(len(my_list)-2) if sum(my_list[i:i+3]) == 3)

In [3]: count
Out[3]: 2
```

For any n:

```
def f(lst: list, n: int):
    return sum(1 for i in range(len(lst)-n+1) if sum(lst[i:i+n])==n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and for each group, get the length and subtract 2 to add to `count`.

```
from itertools import groupby

n = 3
count = 0
for k, g in groupby(my_list):
    if k == True:
        length = sum(1 for _ in g)
        if length >= n:
            count += length - n + 1
print(count)  # -> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list=[True, True, True, True,False, True, True,False]
my_var=0
count_var=0
for i in my_list:
    if i==True:
        my_var+=1
    if my_var==3:
        count_var+=1
        my_var=0
    if i!=True:
        my_var=0
print(count_var)
```

Comment: This doesn't work: it prints `1`. (Once you fix the syntax error, that is.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a one-liner with little change (List Comprehension).

```
consec = 3
print(sum([1 for i in range(len(my_list)) if len(my_list[i:i+consec]) == consec and all(my_list[i:i+consec])]))
```

credits: [Unmitigated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9513184/unmitigated)

Comment: Why did you get rid of `range(len(my_list) - consec + 1)`?

Comment: TBH, that's a good way but it might be confusing people! that's why. Hope you agree to that.

Comment: Why would it be confusing? IMO, the way you're doing it is more confusing, cause you're iterating through indices that you know from the start you don't need. The check `len(my_list[i:i+consec]) == consec` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Agreed! to that

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using an old-school loop with state variables:

```
n = 3

consec = 0
count = 0
for i in my_list:
    if i == True:
        consec += 1
    else:
        consec = 0

    if consec >= n:
        count += 1

print(count)  # -> 2
```

*This is based on [Albert_coding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16417742/albert-coding)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68323988/4518341), but their implementation doesn't work.*

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list=[True, True, True, True,False, True, True,False]
def count_it(n):
    x=0
    count_var=0
    for i in range(len(my_list)-n+1):
        print(my_list[i:i+n])
        for i in my_list[i:i+n]:
            if i==True:
                print(1)
                x+=1
            else:
                print(0)
        if x==n:
            print("successful")
            count_var+=1
        x=0
    print(count_var)

count_it(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use `count`

```py
my_list=[True, True, True, True,False, True, True,False]

if my_list.count(True) == 3:   
   print('we have 3 True in list')
```